# Looker User Access disable or delete in bulk

Tags: looker

I have a bunch of orphaned users I want to delete from looker. Is there way to input a list for that deletion process? Currently I only see deletion or disabling users one at time from admin section. Looker User Access disable or delete in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

There was once an "Admin Power Pack" extension on the marketplace that could help with some bulk admin tasks.

I see it is no longer available on the marketplace, but you may still be able to install it manually: https://github.com/looker-open-source/admin_power_pack#option-2---roll-your-own

If not, then a simple API script might be an option.